# Ways to scroll with a mouse without the wheel or dragging the scroll bar

Tags: mouse, macos

Is there any other means of scrolling using a mouse besides the wheel or dragging the scroll bars on the right side of the window.  Using the wheel is not good for me ergonomically and it is a hassle to move the pointer to the narrow scroll bar and drag that up and down.  In Firefox you clicking the middle button goes into a special mode that enables scrolling by moving the mouse up and down.  But as far as I know Chrome and other applications don't have that feature.

Comment: Can you specify which mouse you have, whether you are using a Mac, and the Operating System you are using?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like someone already answered this on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/303424/can-i-enable-scrolling-with-middle-button-drag-in-os-x)

[SmartScroll](http://marcmoini.com/sx_en.html) is a third party app I've not used, but appears to enable this.

Comment: My apologies for the initial sloppy formatting. Using my phone

Comment: It's worth mentioning that, in that SuperUser thread, the free and open-source alternative mentioned is Hammerspoon. See that thread for how to enable middle click mouse pan with it.